# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types in Grid view Controll

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to achieve from this code is printing Grand Total in gridview footer by using  RowDataBound  method. I declared two variables inside the RowDataBound method . One is Money In and another is Money Out.Gridview has  empty rows.I have two table in database one call Deposit and another call withdraw. I am merging two table by using SqlDataAdapter.I declared two Data Table dt and dt1.Inside the SqlDataAdapter of each data table I passed two SQL Query to retrieve the data from database by using one key which is coming from textbox. Finally I am merging this two Data table by using merge method and displaying in grid view. It works perfectly but when I am trying to get Grand Total of the columns I am having this error Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
    Here is my Sql code.

```
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KHUNDOKARNIRJOR\KHUNDOKERNIRJOR;Initial Catalog=Login;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT  Account_Number AS [Account Number],Amount AS[Money In] from   Deposit  where Deposit.Account_Number='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sdr.Fill(dt);
        SqlDataAdapter sdr1 = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT    WithDraw.Amount AS[Money Out], ACCOUNT.statementamount AS [Balance] FROM ACCOUNT 
                                            INNER JOIN WithDraw 
                                            ON ACCOUNT.Account_Number = WithDraw.Account_Number  
                                            where WithDraw.Account_Number='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", cn);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        sdr1.Fill(dt1);
        dt.Merge(dt1);
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

    int MoneyIn=0;
        int MoneyOut=0;


        // Loop thru each data row and compute total unit price and quantity sold 
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money In") != DBNull.Value)
            {
                MoneyIn += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money In"));
            }
            if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money Out") != DBNull.Value)
            {
                MoneyOut += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money Out"));
            }
        } //// Display totals in the gridview footer
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Grand Total";
            e.Row.Cells[0].Font.Bold = true; 
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = MoneyIn.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[1].Font.Bold = true; 
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = MoneyOut.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[2].Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
}

Please anyone can help me to solve this problem. Thanks 

here is the out put after editing and cheeking the Db null referance but still can not add the grand total
```

Comment: On which line are you receiving the exception? Also, make sure you close your `cn` instance with the `.Close()` method. You should also *always* use parameterized queries.

Comment: Thank for editing @Drew Kennedy

Comment: I can use parameterized queries. Does it Gives expectation result ???@DrewKennedy

Comment: To repeat @DrewKennedy, which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: MoneyIn += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money In"));
        MoneyOut += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money Out"));; This  two line is throwing exception @DrewKennedy

Comment: Looks like the exception would be thrown if "Money In" and "Money Out" are DbNull. Since you're not using a `DataReader`, your best bet may be to set a default value in your database to be `0` and don't allow nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried comparing with `DBNull` before converting?

```
if(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money In") != DBNull.Value)
{
  MoneyIn += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money In"));
}
```

Comment: Yes But still same result @mxmissile

Comment: @MAHossan are you comparing "Money Out" also?

Comment: Yes both @mxmissile

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code you are checking against DBNull with?

Comment: OKK i added the image without using RowDataBound . Please find the image@mxmissile

Comment: @MAHossan no I meant update your `code` to show how your comparing against `DBNull`.

Comment: Without using RowDataBound  event i am getting this output but when i add the  RowDataBound  event i get this error @mxmissile

Comment: Before adding the values of both column Mony In and Money Out

Comment: I tried according you suggestion and some of the help from internet but did not work

Comment: Right, but show what you tried in the question's code.

Comment: I am trying to get grand total of Money In and Money Out column by passing key value from textbox

Comment: Thanks for your time @mxmissile

Comment: mxmissile your suggetion help to solve the Db null problem but still can not adding values from grid views

Comment: You should start a new question for that, since more than likely it is unrelated.

Comment: I have to wait at least 5 days to ask new question you help me to solve one first one can you please help me second part of this question

Answer (score 0):

So if you're getting empty fields back do something with `IsNull()`?  Like this:

```
SELECT  Account_Number AS [Account Number], IsNull(Amount,0) AS[Money In] from   Deposit  where Deposit.Account_Number='" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
```

You may also want to link your two DataTables together using Linq instead as this will give you more control.  That or write a Stored Procedure to give you the correct output in one query/DataTable (the better option).

Also stop with the `= '"+ unsantitised input +"'`! You're making your page extremely easy to hack with SQL Injection. You need to use Parameters.

Comment: What will be answer form this line

Comment: SqlDataAdapter sdr1 = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT    WithDraw.Amount AS[Money Out], ACCOUNT.statementamount AS [Balance] FROM ACCOUNT 
                                        INNER JOIN WithDraw 
                                        ON ACCOUNT.Account_Number = WithDraw.Account_Number  
                                        where WithDraw.Account_Number='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", cn);

Comment: I am afraid say that same result @Hugo Yates

Comment: I changed the SqlQueries according your suggestion but same result

Answer (score 0):

You think you **need** to validate DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money In") before using it, but actually if you are aware that there will be exceptions and the data in these exceptions should just be ignored you don't **need to** validate the data, you can just **ignore it**.

Here is a quick, dirty fix that may help you:

Change:

```
    MoneyIn += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money In"));
```

To

```
    Try
    {
    MoneyIn += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money In"));
    }
    catch {};
```

Change also:

```
    MoneyOut += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money Out"));
```

To

```
    Try
    {
    MoneyOut += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Money Out"));
    }
    catch {};
```

Please notice: this won't stop you exception from happening, it will just catch the exception and ignore the data on it. You program will just ignore the data that cannot be converted to INT, and this is what you were trying to do by validating it.

This can be used when you are aware that exceptions will be thrown and you are willing to ignore these exception because they won't change your program functionality, altough it is not exactly a *"good standards"* solution it works.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion . I will try